# Python login different accounts through a loop from text file

Tags: python-3.x, text, authentication, account

I'm trying to figure out how to read about 10~ accounts from a text file that need to be looped troughout the script.

Basically it logins 1 account finishes the script and skips to login 2 but I'm unsure where to go from here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#define what browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Downloads\chromedriver')

with open("C:\\Users\\pchul\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\1.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       user, password = line.split(':')


driver.get('https://login.webzen.com/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webzen.com%2Fevents%2Fhalloween-2018%2Ftrick-or-treat&Host=www.webzen.com')

        #what boxes to use
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('UserID')
username_box.send_keys(user)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
password_box.send_keys(password)

        #press the actual fcking button
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton')
login_button.submit()

        #click candy
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divLoginAfter"]/button')
submit_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of testing this without access to your usernames and passwords file (which obviously you should not provide!), but I think this is what you want.

```
# Create a list of username, password pairs from your file.
username_password_list = list()
with open("C:\\Users\\pchul\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\1.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       user, password = line.split(':')
       username_password_list.append((user, password))
```

and then we iterate through this list, calling your code inside a for loop:

```
for user, password in username_password_list:
    #define what browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Downloads\chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://login.webzen.com/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webzen.com%2Fevents%2Fhalloween-2018%2Ftrick-or-treat&Host=www.webzen.com')

    username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('UserID')
    username_box.send_keys(user)

    password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
    password_box.send_keys(password)

    # rest of your code goes here.
```

Comment: that semi works, my text file is: username:password then it goes next line to another username:password, but it doesn't seem to go trough my script if theres more then 1 line in text file?

Comment: @Davec9 I've just tested the filereader part with a dummy file and it worked for me (though I did have to add `line.strip().split(':')` which gets rid of spaces and other whitespace at the start and end of strings, so the line return wasn't included in the password). Try adding  `print(user, password)` in the `for line in file` loop to make sure that bit is the problem. I think it's more likely that your code is hanging in the second loop. Does the script finish?

Comment: On further thought I think you may need to recreate the driver and add the `driver.get` inside the second for loop as well so it 'resets' the state for each new user.

Comment: Im unsure what you mean this is what i tryed after reading you're comments:
`code` username_password_list = list()
with open("C:\\Users\\pchul\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\1.txt") as file:
       for line in file:
          user, password = line.split(':')
          line.strip().split(':')
          username_password_list.append((user, password))`code`

Comment: @Davec9 I've edited my answer with the change. I think the problem is not with reading the passwords. I think it's with the second stage. After you've logged in with the first password, the driver is no longer on the log-in page, so when you search for the log-in fields for the second user, it doesn't find them. Creating a new driver for each user should do the trick.